# Resolve nested object property in findBy

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an entity Items which has a ManyToOne relationship to a field on another entity ExceptionType. I want to return a list of Items based on bank number(from Items entity) and itemExceptionType (from the ExceptionType entity). I am using Gradle.

I keep getting this error: No property exceptionType found for type Items! The database is DB2 on the mainframe.

I can search by bank number only and this returns a list of items. When I try to add the exception type to the query, a null list is returned - even though ALL Items have an exception type.

The problem seems to be resolution of the ExceptionType object on Items. I have simplified the query to findBy exception number only but I still get the error.  I have tried various combinations using the _ in the findBy but with no success (e.g., findBy_ExceptionTypeExceptionNumber, findByExceptionType_ExceptionNumber, etc.). They all return the same error.

When I use the _ExceptionType I acutally get: No property _ExceptionType found for type Items!
So with or without the _ it cannot resolve the nested object/property

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Items {

  @Id
  private String itemKey;

  private String bankNbr;

  private BigDecimal itemAmount;

  private String itemPosPayInd;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_EXCEPTION_TYPE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private ExceptionType itemExceptionType;


@Entity
@Data
public class ExceptionType {

private String exceptionTypeValue;

@Id
private String exceptionNumber;


public class AdHocController {
@Autowired
AdHocService adHocService;


@GetMapping(value = "/adhoc-bank-exception/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<Items>> getAdHocItemsByBankException(@RequestParam String bankNbr, @RequestParam (required = false) ExceptionType itemExceptionType) {

    List<Items> itemsList = adHocService.getAdHocItemsByBankException(bankNbr, itemExceptionType);
    log.debug("Getting getAdHocItemsByBankException");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(itemsList, HttpStatus.OK);
}


@Service
public class AdHocService {

@Autowired
private AdHocRepository adHocRepository;


public List<Items> getAdHocItemsByBankException(String bankNbr, ExceptionType itemExceptionType) {
    return adHocRepository.findBy_ExceptionTypeExceptionNumber(itemExceptionType);

}

@Repository
public interface AdHocRepository extends CrudRepository<Items, Long> {


List<Items> findBy_ExceptionTypeExceptionNumber(ExceptionType exceptionNumber);
```

I need it to return a list of Items which all contain the supplied exception number.  However, I get the property reference error.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you're using Spring Data. I suggest the following:

let your `AdHocRepository` interface extend from `JpaRepository` and change your custom repo method's signature to the following.

```
@Repository
public interface AdHocRepository extends JpaRepository<Items, Long> {

    List<Items> findByItemExceptionTypeExceptionNumber(String exceptionTypeNumber);
}
```

Note the naming of the custom repo method:

`findBy<NameOfEntityProperty><NameOfNestedEntityProperty>(...)`